# My SVG doesn't change after changes in the DOM

Tags: ajax, svg, refresh, stroke

I'm trying to change the color of a SVGPathElement but it doesn't refresh. I check it gets the new color showing an alert but I don't see any difference. Is it because my SVG is retrieved by AJAX?

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);
alert(element.getAttribute("stroke"));
element.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "#000000");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: AJAX shouldn't be relevant. Please give us a complete example e.g. a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

you can try and set the stroke using style:

```
element.style.stroke='#0000';
```